# Logo in Navbar only Loading on Landing Page

Tags: html, flask, navbar, bootstrap-5, codeblocks

I am making a website with Bootstrap and Flask and have featured a logo in the navbar. My problem is with the logo only loading on the landing (home) page and not any other pages. The code for the navbar which features the problem is on a base HTML page and is extended to other pages with code blocks.

The code for the navbar on base.html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" data-bs-theme="dark" style="background-color:#FF1801">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
      <img src="static/F1Logo.svg" alt="F1 Logo" width="50%" height="50%">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" style="color:white" href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" style="color:white"  href="/news/">News</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" style="color:white"  href="#">Watch F1 Live</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" style="color:white"  href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Database
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/drivers/">Drivers</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/constructors/">Constructors</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/circuits/">Circuits</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

and is produced on other pages with the code block:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

The image located at `static/F1Logo.svg` loads on the landing page (landing.html) but will not load on other pages, despite the rest of the navbar loading and functioning as intended.

Landing Page:
[image: Landing Page]

Other Pages:
[image: Other Pages]

All pages should look like the result on the landing page.

I have tried swapping the image file type from `.svg` to `.jpg` and removing the sizing attributes (height and width) with both attempts being unsuccessful. I have also tried listing the full file path (`C:\Users\...\static\F1Logo.svg`) without any success.

I am also having the same problem with the icon on the browser tab, which uses the same image (loading on the home page, but no other).
`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="static/F1Logo.svg">`

If anyone has any idea as to what the problem is and how to solve it, any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What does your file structure look like? Are of the html files located in the same directory?

Comment: As I am using Flask, all the HTML files are located in a 'templates' folder inside my project, and the images in the 'static' folder.
HTML Files: ...\Project\templates\FILE NAME.html
Images: ...\Project\static\FILE NAME.jpg (or .svg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem seems to be on the hardcoding of the image source. The rest of the pages cannot find the image.

Try to use url_for instead that should give you the correct url for the image

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" data-bs-theme="dark" style="background-color:#FF1801">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
      <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='F1Logo.svg')}}" />
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" style="color:white" href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" style="color:white"  href="/news/">News</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" style="color:white"  href="#">Watch F1 Live</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" style="color:white"  href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Database
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/drivers/">Drivers</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/constructors/">Constructors</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/circuits/">Circuits</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```